# Suppressing text normalization on copying from Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, unicode, unicode-normalization

Xcode (in fact, many Apple apps) insist on some sort of normalization when copying text to the clipboard. As discussed [here](http://unicode.org/pipermail/unicode/2014-August/000916.html) (among other places) this causes problems when dealing with biblical Hebrew text data files. I'm having this exact problem with a project we're developing. For instance, if I open a project text data file that contains the Unicode character sequence `U+05E4 U+05BC U+05B0 U+05BF`, copy this grapheme cluster to the clipboard, and then paste it somewhere else, it comes out as `U+05E4 U+05B0 U+05BC U+05BF` (the middle two characters reversed).

This reordering doesn't happen with Android Studio or with several other non-Apple applications I've tested on my Mac. It also doesn't happen when I paste from one of these non-Apple apps into Xcode, or when I save a file in Xcode. The problem seems to be specific to the copy operation itself, not with the clipboard or with pasting.

Is there a way to turn off this kind of normalization-on-copy behavior, either in Xcode or system-wide?

In case it makes any difference, I'm running Xcode 8.2.1 on OS X 10.12.3.

Comment: What is the format of the file from which you're copying? Is it UTF-8? UTF-16? UTF-16LE? Is there a BOM? What are your system Language & Region settings? For what it's worth, I couldn't reproduce this. I did `echo $'\u05E4\u05BC\u05B0\u05BF' >foo.txt` which encoded in UTF-8, opened foo.txt in Xcode, copied all, pasted into a new plain text document in TextEdit, saved as bar.txt, and the two were identical. Xcode 8.2, macOS 10.12.3.

Comment: @KenThomases - The file is in UTF-8 (no BOM). However, that doesn't seem to be relevant. The file opens correctly in Xcode. (If I delete characters, they delete in the expected order.) It's only when I copy text from the editor and paste it elsewhere that the characters are reordered. I don't quite understand your experiment. When I run that `echo` command, I get a file that doesn't have any Hebrew characters in it; it has the escape sequences as text (as if it were the String literal `"\\u05E4..."` in Swift).

Comment: @KenThomases - You can enter Unicode characters directly into Xcode using the Unicode hex input method (as described [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1899290?tstart=0), for instance).

Comment: Are you sure you used the `$'...'` syntax? What shell are you using? That's a `bash` feature, I think. I can assure you that I got a Hebrew character. I also used `hexdump` to see the UTF-8 encoded bytes.

Comment: @KenThomases - Yes, I used the `$'...'` syntax; in fact, I copied directly from your comment. And my shell is bash. Is there perhaps some environment variable or something that suppresses escape sequence handling?

Comment: What do get from `printf "\u05E4\u05BC\u05B0\u05BF\n"`?

Comment: @KenThomases - The output is `\u05E4\u05BC\u05B0\u05BF`.

Comment: Very odd. Something's weird about your Terminal or shell. However, we're getting side-tracked. The point is, I created a file (by whatever means) whose content is the UTF-8 byte sequence `d7 a4 d6 bc d6 b0 d6 bf 0a`. I open that in Xcode, select all, copy, paste into TextEdit, save, and it's the same byte sequence.

Comment: @KenThomases - I agree about the side-tracking. But I do the same experiment with copy-and-paste and get a different file. :(

Comment: What are your System Preferences > Language & Region settings? Also, when the file is selected in Xcode's Project navigator, if you select the File Inspector, what's shown for Text Encoding?

Comment: @KenThomases - Preferred languages are English (primary) and Hebrew. Region is United States. Ah. I have keyboard text set to automatically correct spelling. I wonder if because I have Hebrew enabled it is "correcting" the Hebrew. Let me experiment a bit...Nope. Unsetting autocorrect didn't change anything. :(

Comment: Do you have any third-party utilities installed which might be interfering with the clipboard? Xcode extensions? If you create a new user account and log into that, does the problem still occur there?

Comment: @KenThomases - No third-party utilities like that. No Xcode extensions. I'll have to experiment tomorrow with a new user account.